# how to return a model that have specific tags

Tags: laravel

I have a model that can have more then one tag, relationship is defined like this:

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(ListTag::class, 'listing_listtag', 'listing_id', 'tag_id');
}
```

and inside tag model I have:

```
public function listings()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Listing::class, 'listing_listtag');
}
```

I am making a filter where user can select some tags and I should return only models that have all of these tags assigned.

For example if I select "tag_1" this will return all models with that tag assigned to them. Problem I have is if user selects "tag_1" and "tag_2" I need to return only models that have both of those assigned and not models that have only one of them assigned.

Currently I have this:

```
    $listings = Listing::closest($lat, $lng, $radius)

        ->orderBy('distance');

    if($request->tags){
        $listings->whereHas('tags', function($query) use($filter_tags) {
            foreach ($filter_tags as $filter_tag) {
                $query->where('slug', $filter_tag);
            }

        });

        $append += array('tags' => $request->tags);
    }
```

But that returns 0, even though I selected two tags that one of the models has assigned to it so atleast that models should have been returned.

Does the code look ok?

This query is produced:

```
"query" => """
  select count(*) as aggregate from `listings` where (6371 * acos(cos(radians(55.6181338)) \n
                           * cos(radians(lat)) \n
                           * cos(radians(lng) \n
                           - radians(13.0274283)) \n
                           + sin(radians(55.6181338)) \n
                           * sin(radians(lat)))) < ? and exists (select * from `listtags` inner join `listing_listtag` on `listtags`.`id` = `listing_listtag`.`tag_id` where `listing_listtag`.`listing_id` = `listings`.`id` and `slug` = ? and `slug` = ?)
  """
"bindings" => array:3 [▼
  0 => "5"
  1 => "wireless-internet"
  2 => "delivery"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you query the inverse:

- a tag with a where clause (e.g. `$tags = Tag::query()->where('name, 'bla');`
- define the hasOne relation on tag to Listing? (or other model, you aren't really clear if this is the model we're talking about)
- get it by looping the tags and calling the relation

Comment: can't do the inverse since I have categories, tags, and other models tied into the main model. I need to select from the main model

Comment: @Maxlight Can you explain why this won't work exactly. If the relation is via another table, you can use hasmanytrought https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: hi Thomas and thanks for your answers, I have located what is the problem with the query I posted a question about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42025039/return-rows-with-specific-tag if you are good with sql and want to take a look, thanks