# return rows with specific tag

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables

listings
listtags
listing_listtag

listing can have multiple tags assigned to it and those are stored in listing_listtag with forein keys to listings and listtags table

I have a problem to select only a listing which has 2 tags associated with it.

I have this query:

```
select *
from `listtags`
    inner join `listing_listtag` on `listtags`.`id` = `listing_listtag`.`tag_id`
where `listing_listtag`.`listing_id` = 5
   and `slug` = "delivery"
   AND slug = "wireless-internet"
```

and it returns nothing. if I chnage the last AND to OR it now returns

[image]

I would like the query to only return one row where listing_id is 5, how can I do this?

Comment: parentheses... OR has lower precedence than AND, therefore you have to tell mysql that you want to treat the two conditions at a higher precedence. Alternatively you can take a look at the IN keyword.

Comment: Do you mean you want an id having both delivery AND wireless-internet?

Comment: yes, your first answer was correct `slug` in("delivery","wireless-internet") it returns 2 rows, However I now need it to work with exists function, take a look here: http://i.imgur.com/F2V2ceG.png got any advices for that?

Comment: atcually I just realized I about exists and that I can't use it on main query :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method:

```
select ?.listing_id
from listtags lt inner join
     listing_listtag llt
     on lt.id = llt.tag_id
where llt.listing_id = 5 and
      ?.slug in ('delivery', 'wireless-internet')
group by ?.listing_id
having count(*) = 2;
```

The `?` is for the table alias of the table with the column.

Note:  If the data can have duplicates, use `count(distinct slug)`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a pair of brackets:

```
select *
from `listtags`
inner join `listing_listtag` on `listtags`.`id` = `listing_listtag`.`tag_id`
where `listing_listtag`.`listing_id` = 5
and (`slug` = "delivery"
or slug = "wireless-internet")
```

Comment: See the other answer